# Return fetch is empty

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React and would like to call an api and process the result to return it.
But return is empty ... whereas "console.log" is ok ...

In my index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Currencies from './TestApi';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Currencies />
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

In my TestApi.js :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Currencies() {
    const API_URL = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies.json';
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchOptions = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}`);
                const data = await response.json();
                let optionsTmp = '';
                for (var key in data)
                {
                    optionsTmp = optionsTmp.concat('<option key="').concat(key).concat('">').concat(data[key]).concat('</option> ');
                }
                setOptions(optionsTmp);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }

        fetchOptions();
    }, [options]);

    console.log(options);

    return (
        <select>
            {options}
        </select>
    );
}

export default Currencies;
```

In my console.log, i've got 3 calls (!?) :
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZmsG.png)

On my page ... :'(
[select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuAff.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create HTML manually in react, use map in JSX like:

```js
function Currencies() {
    const API_URL = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies.json';
    const [options, setOptions] = useState({}); // default it as object

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchOptions = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(API_URL);
                const data = await response.json();
                setOptions(data);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }

        fetchOptions();
    }, [options]);

    return (
        <select>
            {Object.entries(options).map(([key, value]) => (
              <option key={key}>${value}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    );
}
```